# How do you add a dropdown button to the redactor editor using the plugin API?

Tags: redactor

The docs examples [show you can do it](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/dropdown/) in the `.redactor()` call by setting `buttonsCustom`. The plugins API docs [shows how you can add a single button](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/plugins-api/). But how do you add a dropdown via the plugin API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so looking at the redactor source (latest version 8.2.6) I noticed that you can pass a fourth parameter to the plugin API's `addBtn` function. So, say you want to add a Font Size dropdown menu from inside a plugin:

```
RedactorPlugins.fontSize = {

    init: function(obj) {

        btnCallback = function(obj,event,key) {
            // button actions, if any
        }

        dropdown = {
            small: {
                title: 'Small'
                callback: function(obj,event,key) { //set the font size to small }
            }
            medium: {
                title: 'Medium'
                callback: function(obj,event,key) { //set the font size to medium }
            }
        }

        this.addBtn('fontSize','Change font size', btnCallback, dropdown);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any idea how to set the class for each dropdown item?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using version 9 of redactor the API has changed. This is how to create a dropdown with callbacks. The important thing to not is the 3rd and 4th arguments passed to `buttonAdd`, the 3rd argument should be for a callback function, this must be `false` in order for the dropdown menu to be shown by redactor automatically due to the way the `buttonBuild` functions click handler is written. The 4th argument is the same as version 8.

```
RedactorPlugins.snippets = {
  init: function(){
    var dropdown = {
      quote: {
        title: "Pull Quote",
        callback: function(){
          // callback code here
        }
      },
      accordian: {
        title: "Accordian",
        callback: function(){
          // callback code here
        }
      }
    };
    this.buttonAdd('snippets', 'Snippets', false, dropdown);
  }
};
```

If you need to run a callback when the dropdown is invoked you will need to write the code to show the dropdown in your callback passed as the 3rd argument.

Answer (score 0):

Example to add class name to dropdown item
Eg:-

```
dropdown = {
        small: {
            title: 'Small',
            callback: function(obj,event,key) { //set the font size to small },
            className:'YOURCLASS NAME'
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

JamieD is right. API has changed considerably for the later versions of Redactor. Here's what I used for v9.2.5.

This code adds a dropdown to the toolbar with 2 new buttons in it

if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

```
RedactorPlugins.newbtns = {
    init: function ()
    {
        //biu is bold italics underline
        var newbtns = {};
        newbtns['Bold'] = { title: 'Button 1', callback: this.btn1 };
        newbtns['Italics'] = { title: 'Button 2', callback: this.btn2 };

        this.buttonAdd('newbtns', 'New Buttons', false, newbtns);
        // adding font-awesome buttons
        // u will have to include font-awesome stylesheet separately for this to work
        this.buttonAwesome('newbtns', 'fa-tasks');

    },
    btn1: function(buttonName, buttonDOM, buttonObj, e)
    {
        // add stuff for btn1
    },
    btn2: function(buttonName, buttonDOM, buttonObj, e)
    {
        // add stuff for btn2
    }
};
```

Initialize the redactor with your plugin

```
$('#myTextarea').redactor({
    plugins: ['newbtns']
});
```

See this page for more info - [Redactor plugins](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/plugins-creating/)